# Control the ordering of the output expression from factor

Tags: expression, maxima, display

Can I control the ordering of the output expressions in maxima's factor() function?

```
factor(7*x^2-7*x);
```

returns

```
7*(x-1)*x
```

but I would like to get

```
7*x*(x-1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any simple way to get a specific ordering of terms. Maxima has a pretty strong idea about ordering and it isn't easy to change. My advice is to let it go and just get used to it; I don't think it's worth the trouble to try to change it. In fact, in this case, in which you are trying to change the ordering of `x` and `x - 1`, I don't think there is a way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Robert. I came more or less to the same conclusion after trying things like powerdisp:true and ordergreat(). I understand that Maxima needs an internal normal form to order terms, but it's a shame that the output format cannot be customized further. Do you happen to know if the tex() function might be more flexible in this case, or is it based on the same underlying internal ordering?

Comment: `tex` output has whatever ordering is in force in Maxima, it doesn't have its own ordering.